# How to get the JSP row values to display in another JSP

Tags: jsp

I need a requirement of getting the row values after click on the icon button at the starting point of the row in a JSP page.

Let me explain you in detail,

In JSP1, I have a row as below, Here if I click on "i" button it should display the columns data in a new JSP window (say JSP2).

**Input data: JSP1**

```
      CUSTOMER_NAME CUSTOMER_DOB ORGANIZATION CUSTOMER_ALIAS
"i"    Zhao Tao     01/01/1966       CA            A1
```

**Output format: JSP2**

```
CUSTOMER_NAME  Zhao Tao
CUSTOMER_DOB   01/01/1966
ORGANIZATION   CA
CUSTOMER_ALIAS A1
```

Here, CUSTOMER_DOB is DATE type and remaining all are VARCHAR2 type.

Let me know if you want more details? Thanks.

Comment: can you explain bit more this input data is in one variable[like String] or each data has their own variables

Comment: Some one help on this please...